# set a limit on concurrent SSH/SFTP connections to 2 per user

Tags: sshd

I made the changes in /etc/security/limits.conf

```
test        hard    maxlogins       2
sftptest    hard    maxlogins       2
```

- After above entries I have tested below scenarios

  1. Open 2 putty sessions when I tried to open 3rd sessions it disconnect automatically (Working fine with ssh user not for sftp user )
  2. Open 2 putty sessions when I am trying to open 3rd session from the filezilla / winscp connection disconnected automatically (Working fine with ssh user )
     3.When I am trying to open 3 sessions in filezilla/winscp I am able to open 3 sessions ( Not working)
  3. when I am trying to open 3 sessions in filezilla/winscp with sftp users I am able to open all three sessions 
     -Is there any difference in putty client and winscp/filezilla ?
     -SSH users having shell login but sftp users don't have shell login
- Is there any chance to  limit the connections 2 for sftp users?

I am pretty new to Linux.

Comment: Two options using `MaxSession` or `firewall`. The first will work if your ssh supports it!

Comment: Can you please let me know how to do it from firewall side ?

Comment: Try this rule: `sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule iptables -I INPUT -p TCP --dport 22 --syn -m connlimit --connlimit-above 2 -j REJECT`, this only limits per ip not per user!

Comment: Thanks for the reply , but i am looking for user side .

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the process count for that user. 
During a scp, 3 processes are created with root, sshd and sftptest(in your case) users.
So you can limit the max process count for that user in /etc/security/limits.conf

```
sftptest hard nproc 2
```

This is not a very efficient way because you block the connection after it is authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know that this is a definitive answer:

- I would expect 'ssh' (or access via console / getty) to spawn a login shell
- I would NOT expect sftp (nor, e.g. starting a terminal emulator in a X window session) to spawn a login shell, but I would expect a shell to be started

There are important differences a login shell and non-login shell. A "login shell" will execute the profile on startup, however a non-login shell won't (it will execute the shell rc file).

I must admit that I am hazy on the underlying mechanisms that differentiate between the 2 session types. But I believe the limit is enforced via pam_limits.so on Linux.